# Unexpected end of input error in line 1 of JavaScript .js file

Tags: javascript, input, google-chrome-devtools

Chrome Dev Tools throws the following JavaScript error:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input ... application.js:1`

application.js file (first two lines):

```
var firstTimeExecuting = true;   //should execute only once...above function call.
function guessAnal(guess) { ...  //Analyze the guess.
```

Comment: Can you add the complete code?

Comment: that is quite the function name

Answer (score 12):

Often times a line 1 error indicates that there is a major syntax error in the script somewhere that is preventing it from parsing correctly. Ignore the line number and carefully check your whole js script. If you're really having issues try breaking it into several js files, that way you can see which is failing (a syntax error in a js script causes that entire script to be ignored).

Comment: Also try a js validator -- http://jslint.com/, http://jshint.com/
There are many offline tools as well. This can be faster than manual debugging.